# i<=: Expression is not complete; more tokens expected. ksh

Tags: shell, unix, expression, token, ksh

i get this error: `i<=: Expression is not complete; more tokens expected.` This is the code:

```
vr=`$line`
set sep_mx=`echo $vr | awk '{
    n=split($0,x,"@#;")
    print n
}'`

echo $sep_mx
i=1 && while ((i<=$sep_mx))
do                                       
    echo $vr | awk -v er=$i '{
         n=split($0,x,"@#;")
         print x[er]
    }'
    ((i+=1))
done
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: `while [ $i<=$sep_mx ]` maybe?

Comment: Mmh yeah but now i have new error `=: Cannot find or open the file.`

Comment: Execute the script with ksh -xv to track down the error.

Comment: And I think you want `$i <= $sep_mx`

Comment: nope..same error also with `$i <= $sep_mx`

Comment: For integer comparision in `[...]` (or `[[...]]`), use `-le`. The `<` is interpreted as a redirection operator.

Comment: Are you sure `sep_mx` has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question, the error message already
explains where the error occurs:

In `i<=` in `i<=: Expression is not complete; more tokens expected.` is the result of the expansion of the contents of `((i<=$sep_mx))`.

This would happen if `$sep_mx` contained an empty string, which in turn, would be the consequence of

```
vr=`$line`
```

resulting in a `vr` that does not contain the delimiter string you include in the split() function in the awk line.

Note that awk split()'s third argument is a *regular expression*.  If you want to split on any of the characters in "@#;", you should turn it into a character set by enclosing it in square brackets.

Compare:

```
$ echo "@fee#fie@foe" | awk '{ print split($0,x,"[@#;]") }'
4
```

With:

```
$ echo "@fee#fie@foe" | awk '{ print split($0,x,"@#;") }'
1
```

Answer (score 1):

ok , got that thing working.

Logic : code that would take a string , break it into words based on a defined delimiter and put each as a array element.

To make things a bit more simple i removed the other two delim option (# and ;) specified in your question.

working code :

```
Kaizen ~/so_test $ cat zawk1.sh
echo "entter a line : " ;
read line ;

vr="$line";

      sep_mx=`echo $vr| awk '{ n=split($0,x,"@"); print n }'` ; 
      echo $sep_mx ;  ## here the number of substring produced is calc.

      while [ $i -le $sep_mx ]
      do
          ## would print individual substring one at a time as the counter increases.
          echo $vr | awk -v er=$i '{ n=split($0,x,"@"); print x[er] }' ;
          i=$(( $i + 1 ));
      done
```

output :

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test $ ./zawk1.sh
 entter a line :
 hello@world@how@are@you
 5
 hello
 world
 how
 are
 you
```

hope this helps !!

Comment: helps me a lot thanks. Another one thing, if i would extract for example only the first line? In this case "hello".

Comment: ` echo "hello@world@how@are@you" | awk '{ n=split($0,x,"@"); print x[1] }' `