# Executing SSH with bash is prompting for password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am having problems running SSH from a shell script once I send the script into the background. The error is "expected more tokens" I read on line that I could nest the SSH call in a bash command as follows, but doing so prompts for a password, and even when I enter the correct password (which I don't want to do) it won't work.

This prompts for password from the command line

```
bash -c "ssh NJ\\NJDSSINFADM@dc01nj2dwifdv02.nj.core.him pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TEST"
```

This works from the command line or script in the foreground, but not when I run the script in the background

```
ssh NJ\\NJDSSINFADM@dc01nj2dwifdv02.nj.core.him pmcmds DFD_ETIME wf_TEST
```

Comment: Is that the exact error message? Or is it `Expression is not complete; more tokens expected` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942832/i-expression-is-not-complete-more-tokens-expected-ksh)?

Comment: more tokens expected, sorry.

Comment: Take a look at the question I linked to, the problem is not coming from this line.

Comment: I did. Here is the exact code in my script which works just fine as long as I don't send the script into the bg:  jstat=$(ssh NJ\\NJDSSINFADM@dc01nj2dwifdv02.nj.core.him pmcmds $fl $wf)
   let jstat=`echo $jstat|sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`

Comment: How do you put carriage rt and lines into replies here?

Comment: Thanks I think I see what the problem is. I hard coded the arguments into the command and it worked!

Comment: Don't use `let`. That treats the value as an arithmetic expression.

Comment: The problem is I need to use variables but it appears that when I send the script into the bg, the variables, filled from command line args, are not retraining their value.

Comment: Just use `jstat=$(echo ...)`

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you're doing. It's not showing up correctly in the comment because backtick is a markdown character.

Comment: Let is used after the exec to check for numeric values in jstat.

Comment: Actually, NON number values

Comment: But you're not doing arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `let` to assign variables with strings. It treats the value as an arithmetic expression, and your value is not intended to be treated that way.

```
jstat=$(echo $jstat|sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g')
```

You also don't need to use an external command to remove characters from a string, you can use the parameter expansion operator for substitution.

```
jstat=${jstat//[^0-9]/}
```

See the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for an explanation of this syntax.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove char from the string, I'm checking for the exit status from the command.

Comment: I don't see how you're doing that with `sed` substitution.

Comment: If you want better help, post the script code that's getting the error.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't like that I'm passing variables when I run in the BG, but it works just fine if I run in the FG

Comment: There's no way that it could matter whether it's FG or BG, so the problem is with your script.